# Save data into file using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, save

I am developing a webpage using jquery which let me manipulate images easily.

I have set some buttons in which a client (through a browser) can input some information (for example "0" or "1"). My main problem is that I need to save that information into a file in the server, and I have not found a easily way to do it.

Any suggestion to do that? I have read that using ajax it can be done, but I am very confused about using it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to write a file directly to the server using jQuery.  You will need to do this with a server-side language like php, ruby, python, java, node.js etc.  You would use AJAX to make a request to your server-side application written in a language like the one's I previously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clarifies the doubts I had.