# Jquery Ajax Post Data to Local File

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, file, save

I am trying to read contents of a local text file into text area, then modifying textarea and subsequently saving modified text area value into the same local file. I cannot use server side code so trying this with Jquery Ajax post method. My html looks like this -

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit Properties</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/graph/graph.js"></script>
        <script>    
var testpath;   
var buildpath;  
var dataOnFile;
var buildnum;
    function loadFile() {
        var URL = "somepath";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", URL, false);
        xhttp.send(""); 
        return xhttp.response;      
    }

    function edit(){    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //console.log(loadFile());
        $("#area").val(loadFile());//load the contents correctly
        $("#save").click(function()
            {
                testpath = window.location;
                buildpath=(testpath+"").replace("somepath1","");
                buildpath= buildpath + "somepath2";
                dataOnFile=$("#area").val();            
                console.log(dataOnFile);//logs updated value of text area
                $.ajax({
                  type : "POST",
                  async:false,                
                  data : dataOnFile,    
                  url:buildpath,
                  dataType : "text",
                  success: function(data) {                 
                    alert("File Saved");
                  }
                });
            });
        });
    }
    </script>
<body onload="edit()">
        <p>
            <textarea rows="50" cols="100" id="area"></textarea>
            <input type='button' value='Save File' id="save"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This works without error but my changes are NOT saved into a file. Any pointers to resolve this?

Comment: How can you change anything on your server not using server side code ? :-) You're trying to send a cake by the cellphone

Comment: *"I cannot use server side code"* Then what you are trying isn't possible.

Comment: yeap, and what's on server side even you can't change it?

Comment: The file is on my local machine.

Comment: Imagine a world where you could update any page on the internet just by posting a request to it's url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save data into file using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286015/save-data-into-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript was designed in a way that denies access to the file system. If you want to mannupilate files, you should probably use a server side language like php. This tutorial might help you get what your trying to do:

[Beginners guide to Ajax with PHP](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)